# Ubuntu, Doom Emacs: fails to run /bin/doom

Tags: install

I am trying to install Doom Emacs. I have installed all dependencies but when I run installation command I get this:

`~/.emacs.d/bin/doom install`

`Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, mule-util`

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: I know nothing about this "Doom Emacs", but a quick glance at the github page says this: "Run `bin/doom doctor` to detect common issues in your development environment." Maybe that will give you more information.

Comment: ```bin/doom``` does work itself. And I did not find any information on how to fix that or what possible issue might be

Answer (score 0):

When I upgrade my Doom Emacs I had a problem like you.
first of all you need to check your home directory with `ls -la`
if you seen a .config directory and then if you seen your emacs directory, you have to change your doom Emacs environment in `.bashrc, .bash_profile`

That was my old path before upgrade: `#export PATH="$HOME/.config/.emacs.d/bin:$PATH"`

That is new: `export PATH="$HOME/.config/emacs/bin:$PATH"`